# Removing Firestore SnapshotListener

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am currently working on a valet app. I have two table views one for the Location of the worker, and then another that when you click on a location the cars that are under that location come up in the new tableview.

My current problem is that when I click on a new location the old snapshot listener is still on and if an update happens under that location the second table view changes back to the original location.

I tried to do what they say by removing listener but then it just doesn't work at all.

This is my code below

```swift
// func to select the individual row
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
 
 switch tableView {
 case SelectLocationTableView:
   do {
     if (allowed == false){ // postin data in table already but not reloading the page yet
       Authenticate(title: "hi", message: "hi")
       Location = postData[indexPath.row]
       oldLocation=Location
     }
   }
   do {
     if (allowed == true) {
       allowed = false
       Location = postData[indexPath.row]
       CarsRequestedTableView.reloadData()
       DisplayLocations()
     }
   }
   
 case CarsRequestedTableView:
   CarSelected = postCars[indexPath.row]
   WorkWithCar()
   
 default:
   print(Error.self)
 }
}

// function to pull the location based on the cell you click on
func DisplayLocations (){
 let listener = db.collection("Requested").document(Location).collection("Requested").addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
   guard (querySnapshot?.documents) != nil else {
     print("Error fetching documents: \(error!)")
     return
   }
   
   self.postCars.removeAll()
   for document in querySnapshot!.documents {
     let post = document.documentID
     self.postCars.append(post)
     self.CarsRequestedTableView.reloadData()
     self.DisplayAlert(title: "NEW REQUEST!", message: "CHECK FOR NEW REQUEST!")
   }
 }
 
}
```

Comment: Three things. 1) Please don't call a function within itself e.g. `CarsRequestedTableView.reloadData()` within `didSelectRowAt` will cause that same function to be called again. This can lead to an infinite loop and app instability. 2) It's not the best idea to refresh a tableView inside a tight loop `self.CarsRequestedTableView.reloadData()`. That can cause flicker and a weird UI experience for the user. Last thing about asking questions here on SO - *it just doesn't work at all* - is super vague. It does work but without seeing your implementation we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the listener registration in a (private) instance variable in your table view controller, and call its `remove()` method when you're ready to stop listening. The [Firebase iOS Quickstart repo](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios) has a couple of classes that show how to do this, here is an example I took from [RestaurantsTableViewController](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/blob/master/firestore/FirestoreExample/RestaurantsTableViewController.swift#L63):

```swift
class RestaurantsTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

  // ...
  
  // the data that's displayed in the table view
  private var restaurants: [Restaurant] = []
  private var documents: [DocumentSnapshot] = []

  // this method removes any existing listener and sets up a new query
  fileprivate var query: Query? {
    didSet {
      if let listener = listener {
        listener.remove()
        observeQuery()
      }
    }
  }

  // this is where you keep the listener registration
  private var listener: ListenerRegistration?

  // set up the new snapshot listener and map documents to data
  fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    stopObserving()

    // Display data from Firestore, part one
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { [unowned self] (snapshot, error) in
      guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
        print("Error fetching snapshot results: \(error!)")
        return
      }
      let models = snapshot.documents.map { (document) -> Restaurant in
        let maybeModel: Restaurant?
        do {
          maybeModel = try document.data(as: Restaurant.self)
        } catch {
          fatalError("Unable to initialize type \(Restaurant.self) with dictionary \(document.data()): \(error)")
        }

        if let model = maybeModel {
          return model
        } else {
          // Don't use fatalError here in a real app.
          fatalError("Missing document of type \(Restaurant.self) at \(document.reference.path)")
        }
      }
      self.restaurants = models
      self.documents = snapshot.documents

      if self.documents.count > 0 {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = nil
      } else {
        self.tableView.backgroundView = self.backgroundView
      }

      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
  }

  // this is where you stop the listener
  fileprivate func stopObserving() {
    listener?.remove()
  }
  
  /// ...


}
```